# c# datagridview sort autogenerated column long datetime

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

i've a datagridview with column generated from xml.
One column is generated by script and convert xml string to datetime and i showed as longDateString.
Then i've added button to sort thath column,but sort result isn't correct(order is casual):

```
dgv.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[2], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

why sorting didn't works?

Comment: I get it's ordered alphabetically since the data is now of type String?

Comment: I guess you have no choice but to implement a custom LongDateStringFormat that will implement Comparator and redefine the compare() method to suit your needs.

Comment: how to make it? result is same if i didn't convert to any format.

Comment: You need to give some more information to be able to answer this question properly. Mainly you need to let up know how you are providing data to the grid (what is the type of your binding source) and how you are formatting the datetime. So long as you have a binding source that supports sorting and have DateTime as the actual column source, this works very easily. Also, you should be doing the datatime formatting in the CellFormatting event.

Comment: i ha a dataset,not databindig...

Comment: How are you providing data to the grid? Was your comment 'i have a dataset'? how do you use it if not databinding (setting the datasource)? What is the type of the datetime column? How do you format the datetime? Do other columns allow sorting? All these are important pieces of information that should be in your question.

Comment: ops,my comment is "I haven dataset,not databinding".Datagrid is provided by dataset.datecolumn format is longdatetime.other row allow sort automatic and it work.